# setting ng-bind-html on an iterating table in cshtml

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am setting ng-init

```
 <td ng-init="myInit='myInit='@deal.OriginText')'">
```

based on the foreach statement below

```
@foreach (var deal in @Model.Deals.Take(Model.NumberOfFaresToDisplay ?? 6))
```

Inside of my html everything looks fine.

```
@deal.OriginText // returns the city && correct for each td
```

Inside of my javascript I set myInit to a scope key value pair

```
 var currentFlight = scope.myInit; //exists inside of a ng-click function
```

CurrentFlight  is set on

```
scope.openPriceChart = function (index) {
    currentFlight //always the value of last ng-init on td from foreach
 }
```

Not sure how to get the correct one.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to use the value set during `ng-init` when the user clicks on a `td` element ?

Comment: Yes.  Not sure how to pass it through.   I was trying a parameter in the myInit function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While nothing is wrong with your code, the current setup is overwriting the `myInit` value, so you always see the last one set. Try this option

Using data attributes here to get the value set

```
<td data-myvalue = '@deal.OriginText' ng-click="DoSomething($event)">@deal.OriginText</td>
```

Script update

```
 $scope.DoSomething= function(abc){
   console.log(abc.originalTarget.dataset.myvalue);
 }
```

This is from my understanding that you are a attempting to get the value of `@deal.OriginText` set on `td` element. An alternative/better approach would be to directly pass `DoSomething('@deal.OriginText')` instead of `$event` .Let us know if this is not what you wanted..

Comment: Nice!  i was trying something very similar to this.  I'll test this too.  hope it works!  thanks

Comment: @stevek  Nice, So are you still passing `$event` or using `@deal.OriginText` ?